# How to turn off JS/CSS background effect on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, effects

I love cool JS/CSS background effects, but on many slower devices they take up a lot of CPU usage and really bog down the browser. A really good example is this site: http://volar.makwan.net/index02.html

The code in the HTML for this effect is `<div id="fss" class="fss full-screen "></div>` - is there a way to disable this DIV when the user trolls away from #home so resources aren't dedicated to the background effect when it isn't visible?

Comment: remove the class / id that applies it when the div is off screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the class (or id) of the div which is causing the resource drain when the div leaves the viewport (ie the screen). You can even add a temporary class while it is off the screen if you wish.

Take a look at the code snippet below. Although you can't see it, the green box loses the class `green` when it goes off the screen, and gets the class `orange` added to it instead (inspect the element to see it change).
Then when it comes back onto the screen the div gets the class `green` and loses the class `orange`:

```js
function isElementInViewport(el) {
    let rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return rect.bottom > 0 && rect.right > 0 && rect.left < (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) && rect.top < (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight);
}

let isVisible = true;

window.onscroll = function() {
  let myGreenBox = document.getElementById('green-box');
  if(!isElementInViewport(myGreenBox) && isVisible) {
    myGreenBox.classList.add("orange");
    myGreenBox.classList.remove("green");
    
    console.log("Green Box style removed");
    isVisible = false;
  } else if(isElementInViewport(myGreenBox) && !isVisible){
    myGreenBox.classList.add("green");
    myGreenBox.classList.remove("orange");
    console.log("Green Box style added");
    isVisible = true;
  }
  
};
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.green {
  background-color: lime;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

.container {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="green-box" class="box green">

  </div>
</div>
```

You can apply this idea to `<div id="fss" class="fss full-screen "></div>` to 'disable' it when it is off the screen.