# what is alternative for :visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a performace issue due to **:visible**

I have a code where i need to see visibility

```
layouts.filter(":visible")
```

Due to this :visible i am getting a performance issue

can you please suggest any better native JS way.

I have tried

```
isVisible = function(elem){
   return !!(elem.offsetWidth || elem.offsetHeight);
}
```

still i see same performance issue mainly in ie11.

**What is the better alternative of :visible in perspective of performance**

Comment: display:none? Does it help?

Comment: Define "*performance issue*". The shown examples most definitely are not a problem by themselves. There seems to be another issue with your code.

Comment: This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36933809/9758920 To add some parts of the API: "Using this selector heavily can have performance implications, as it may force the browser to re-render the page before it can determine visibility. Tracking the visibility of elements via other methods, using a class for example, can provide better performance." And to add further: elem.offset* can cause a reflow too!

Comment: This: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52532774/how-to-turn-off-js-css-background-effect-on-scroll/52533227#52533227, might be able to help you, such that you can hide elements using a class when they go off-screen

Answer (score 1):

I think that check display property is much more ease

```
isVisible = function(el) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    return (style.display === 'none')
}
```